# iphone as mobile web server

Tags: iphone, mobile, webserver, embeddedwebserver

Am writing an application for iphone to run as mobile web server by assigning one IP address to it.How can we deploy mobile web server in iphone without using servers man application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a framework like Robbie Hanson's [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) to respond to web requests in an iPhone app.  However I think you are trying to ask whether it's possible to to run a web server in the background, without having an app running.

The answer is that it's not possible, unless you have a jailbroken device.